# Angular - Toggle sidenav open/close from within the sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav

The Angular materials sidenav can be toggled open using a hamburger button on the nav menu.
However, when the side menu comes out there is no X button to close it. You have to "click off of it" to close it.

I would like to place a button on the sidenav that will toggle it closed.

The toggle function is in the header component, not the sidenav child component.
So how do I "reach" the toggle function in the header component FROM within the sidenav component?

header.component.html:

```
<mat-drawer-container class="header" [hasBackdrop]="false">
  <mat-drawer #drawer mode="side" position="end" class="drawer">
    <app-sidemenu (sidenav)="toggle($event)"></app-sidemenu>                        // The sidenav
  </mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="toolbar">
      <span class="title-text" (click)="open('/home')">My Website Title</span>
      <app-navmenu></app-navmenu>
      <button                                                                       // The hamburger button to toggle sidenav open close        
        mat-icon-button
        class="toolbar-item"
        (click)="toggleDrawer()"
      >
        <mat-icon id="drawerButton">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-toolbar>
  </mat-drawer-content>
```

header.component.ts :

```
export class HeaderComponent {

  constructor() {}

  @ViewChild('drawer', { static: false }) drawer!: MatDrawer;

  toggle(action: string) {
    if (action === 'toggle') {
      this.drawer.toggle();             // toggle the sidenav open/closed.
    }
  }
}
```

sidenav.component.html:

```
<div class="menu" id="sideNavDrawer" #sideNavDrawer>
  <div class="menu-header">
    <div class="logout">
      <button
        mat-icon-button
        class="toolbar-item"
        (click)="toggle()"                      // How to toggle sidenav closed ???
      >
        <mat-icon id="drawerButton">cancel</mat-icon>
      </button>

  <div class="menu-item" (click)="open('products/manage')">
    <span>Menu Link 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <span>Menu Link 2</span>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

So in the sidenav.component.ts file, how do I get that toggle button in sidenav to talk to the toggle() function in the header and close the drawer?

I can't seem to refence the drawer itself from within sidenav?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easy way to achieve toggling drawer from another component is creating service and inject it in the header this is a working example : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-toggle-sidenav-in-another-component?file=src/app/layouts/side-nav.service.ts)

Comment: Thanks, Souhail. I'll give it a go. I was thinking of using "@Input" and "@Output" but this seems cleaner.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer because it did work. I ended up just using "@Input" to do it though as there was only one Parent talking to one child. Tehe toggle function was int he Parent, so just had to pass it as an "@Input" to the child to get it to work. If this was scaled to more than one component your answer would be best.